# Firebase Cloud Functions and Google Security Alerts.

Tags: firebase

When I run a Firebase Cloud Functions, I get a security alert on my phone.

"Trying to sign in from another computer? "

Then I have to say yes, for it to continue. How can I grant Firebase access so it will stop sending me security alert notification?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: use a service account which acts on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, all I had to do is to add the domain URL of my app to the authorized domain in Develop -> authentication -> Authorized domain.